# Toast background color changed after changing app background color from styles

Tags: java, android, themes, android-toast

I have changed the background color of my app by adding "#FFFFFF" to my styles.xml file. The problem is, that the background color of Toasts in my app have changed as well.

Is there any way to change it back or to prevent the overriding of the background color of the Toast?

Cheers!

styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

The style attribute used for the toast is toastFrameBackground but you cannot use it because it has not been exported, which means it is not part of public.xml, which means this attribute is not available for non-platform/third-party applications. It sounds complicated to change the background toast color app wild.

However you can set the background you want:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, stringResId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
View view = toast.getView();
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_background);
```

Or you can make your own Toast

```
Toast toast = new Toast(context);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_toast_layout, null);
toast.setView(view);
```

Hope it helps!